# Convergence to measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Let $u_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a given uniformly bounded sequence in $L^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Then there exists a bounded measure $\mu$ such that $$\int_{\Omega}u_n\,\psi\to\int_{\Omega}\psi\,d\mu$$ for all simple functions $\psi$.

I am not getting how to prove the above argument. Can anyone please help me how to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's surely related to the fact that the closed ball is compact in the weak star topology (which means that there exists a measure $\mu$ such that the claim holds for a sub-sequence of $u_n$). Unfortunately I'm not sure how to extend this result to the actual sequence.

Comment: In a second thought, there is no way you can expect such a result. Think about that if $u_n = 0$ for even $n$ and $u_n=1$ for odd $n$, there is no way you can find such a $\mu$. You can only hope for a convergence sub-sequence.

Comment: Upto a subsequence is fine, but can you kindly elaborate your answer. It will really clear my doubt.

Comment: I post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer to the question (with the modification that the sequence may not converge but a sub-sequence does - see comments) follows immediately from a well known result in functional analysis.

Let's begin from the start, suppose we have a Banach space $X$ (in your case $X=L^1(\Omega)$). One can construct the dual space $X^\star$ of $X$ to be the set $$X^\star : = \{ \varphi:X\rightarrow\mathbb{C} : \varphi \text{ is a continuous functional}\}$$

In the case where $X=L^1(\Omega)$ Riesz theorem gives a general form for a function on $X$. By Riesz theorem every function $\varphi:L^1(\Omega)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ takes the form 
$\varphi(f) = \int fg d\mu$ for some $g\in L^\infty(\Omega)$. In other every functional of $L^1(\Omega)$ corresponds to an element in $L^\infty(\Omega)$. The other direction is also true, given a function in $g\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ the map $f\mapsto \int fg d\mu$ is a continuous functional of $L^1(\Omega)$.

**A norm on $X^\star$**: Elements in $X^\star$ are linear functions $\varphi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and so you can consider the norm

$$\|\varphi\| = \sup_{\{x : \|x\|=1\}} \|\varphi(x)\|$$

**The weak$^\star$ topology on $X^\star$** : The space $X^\star$ is clearly a vector space. Moreover, every element $x\in X$ correspond to a function of $X^\star$ (in some sense $X$ embedded in $(X^\star)^\star$) by $x (\varphi) = \varphi(x)$ (where $x\in X$ and $\varphi\in X^\star$). Let's call these functionals "simple functionals". The weak$^\star$ topology on $X^\star$ is defined to be the intersection of all typologies on $X^\star$ with respect to which all simple functionals are continuous.

We can finally state the theorem from which you can derive the answer to your question

> **Banach Alauglu Theorem**: The closed ball in $X^\star$  $$B:=\{\varphi\in X^\star : \|\varphi\|\leq 1\}$$ 
>   is compact with respect to the weak$^\star$ topology.

Using this theorem your question becomes very easy:
Indeed, we define functions $\mu_n:L^1(\Omega)\rightarrow S^1$ by $$\mu_n (\psi) = \int u_n\psi d\mu$$

Then $$\|\mu_n\|  = sup_{\{\psi : \|\psi\|_{L^1}=1\}} \int \left|u_n \psi \right|d\mu$$

Since $\int |u_n \psi| d\mu \leq  \|u_n\|_\infty \int |\psi| d\mu=\|u_n\|_\infty \|\psi\|_1 $ we conclude that $\|\mu_n\| = \|u_n\|_\infty$ which is totally bounded, say by $M$ but without loss of generality we can take $M=1$.

We conclude that $\mu_n \in B$, hence there exists a convergence **sub-sequence** in the weak$^\star$ -topology. In particular there exists $\mu\in B$ such that $\mu_{n_k}\rightarrow \mu$ with respect to that topology.

Again by the Riesz theorem this means that there exists $u\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\mu(\psi) = \int u \psi d\mu$.

Finally you remind yourself what is the weak$^\star$-topology on $X^\star$. It means that for all $x\in X$ the functions $x(\varphi) = \varphi(x)$ is continuous. In particular it means that for all $x\in X$ we have $x(\mu_{n_k})\rightarrow x(\mu)$ and so $\mu_{n_k}(x)\rightarrow \mu (x)$. Recall that $X=L^1(\Omega)$ and so we can take $x=\psi$ for some simple function $\psi$. We have that $\mu_{n_k}(\psi)\rightarrow \mu(\psi)$ which is the desired result.